# passport-jwt returns unauthorized when I go to /admin page on my web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to get the user logged in using passport and jwt token. I manage to generate jwt token successfully but when I go to /admin page by typing in the browser I am getting the unauthorized message. I have read all the answer here but they aren't helping me out.

My passport.js file

```
try {
    passport.use('signin', new LocalStrategy(
        function(username, password, done) {
            Users.findOne({username: username}, (err, user) => {
                if (err) { return(err)}
                if(!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' })}
                if (!checkUser(password, user.password)) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' }); }
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
    ))
} catch (error) {
    return done(error);
}

passport.use(new JWTstrategy({
    secretOrKey: config.get('jwt.tokenKey'),
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken()
}, async(token, done) => {
    try {
        return done(null, token.user);
    } catch (err){
        done(err);
    }
}))
```

My login-controller file: -

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    passport.authenticate('signin', {session:false}, async(err,user,info) => {
        try {
            if (err || !user) {
                console.log(err);
            }

            req.login(user, {session:false}, err => {
                if (err) res.send(err);

                const body = { username: user.username};

                const token = jwt.sign( {user:body}, config.get('jwt.tokenKey'));
                res.json({ success: true, 
                    token: 'Bearer ' + token });
            });
        } catch (error) {
            return next(error);
        }
    })(req, res);
})
```

My admin page file: -

```
router.get('/',  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function (req,res) {
    res.render('./../views/admin/admin.pug');
})
```

Comment: How are you sending the token in the header?

Comment: I posted all my code above. All I do is res.json()

Comment: Yeah but after you login, the API returns a token, right? So when you make further requests (ex: to the /admin page), you have to provide that token as a header in your request. Are you doing that, and if so, how?

Comment: I am not doing that since I haven't seen this any tutorials. I have posted my whole admin page code. Please help me out on how to do this?

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information. What does your login page do, does it do anything with the token you've returned via `res.json({ success: true, token: 'Bearer ' + token });`?

Comment: I want user to login on login page. Then I want them to be able to access certain sections of the page like /admin once jwt token has been generated.

Comment: I am trying to create a replacement for the session. I want jwt token to be available universally on my site no matter where you are